# linux sort doesn't work for me

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sorting, sh

I have a sort command like the following,

```sh
sort -t $'\t' -k2,2nr
```

And a snippet of result is like

```sh
apple rind  9.983498736703696E-5    9.821524318539816E-5    1.6197441816387907E-6
barren apple    9.972712868635945E-5    1.1021253359685341E-4   -1.0485404910493957E-5
kept apple  9.95533841217251E-6 2.2368286282260593E-5   -1.2412947870088083E-5
apple become    9.954637398594461E-6    1.81625156251578E-5 -8.207878226563337E-6
straggling apple    9.953618126913039E-6    1.408307957656849E-5    -4.129461449655451E-6
apple big   9.948337410841929E-5    1.0583294657729803E-4   -6.349572468878738E-6
ibm apple   9.946711193013018E-4    8.75459103803131E-4 1.1921201549817075E-4
apple rootstock 9.93574943786854E-4 9.333210264003837E-4    6.025391738647017E-5
smaller apple   9.933352410426696E-5    1.0778732631866422E-4   -8.453802214397258E-6
cream apple 9.93011589875499E-4 9.235511228493648E-4    6.946046702613425E-5
```

I want to sort the second column of the table, but the result shows it doesn't work as I expected.
Could anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: The indentation doesn't look like the columns are separated by tabs. Could that be your problem?

Comment: this may be a better fit at [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Kay It is separated by tab

Comment: put a space between the `-k` option and its arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-n` doesn't do scientific notation. Use `-g` instead.